# Why $_GET is NULL in my Yii custom component?

Tags: yii2

I have created component and added in bootstrap.
This is my config:

```
'bootstrap' => ['setGeo', 'log'],
...
'components' => [
...
   'setGeo' => [
            'class' => 'frontend\components\setGeo',
        ],
...
]
...
```

In my component I need $_GET variables

```
class setGeo extends yii\base\Component
{

    public function init() {

    var_dump(Yii::$app->request->get()); // or var_dump($_GET);

    }
}
```

But I get *array(0) { }*  in result...

How can I get $_GET params array  in my Component?

Comment: var_dump(Yii::$app->request->get()); is OK on Controller

Answer (score 1):

You have added your component to `bootstrap`, it means that it will be initialized at the begging of app lifetime, before request is processed and GET params are extracted for path. I'm not sure what your component is trying to do, but using `bootstrap` is probably the wrong way to trigger it. I suggest to use [`Application::EVENT_AFTER_REQUEST`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-application#EVENT_AFTER_REQUEST-detail) to trigger this task, GET params should be available at this point.

Comment: Yes. I used behavior instead component and it works now...